# C# Sending an SMTP Email (yeh, I know)

Tags: c#, smtp

I realise this question has been asked a hundred times, but sadly I still have the same issue.  So I've converted someone's Vb.Net solution on here to C#, but I get as far as the smtpClient.Send and my application hangs until it times out.  I've allowed the exe through the firewall, so that isn't the issue.  Any assistance in what I've missed/got wrong would be greatly appreciated.  Here's my code

```
        MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
        mailMsg.To.Add("a@b.com");
        // From
        MailAddress mailAddress = new MailAddress("x@y.com");
        mailMsg.From = mailAddress;

        // Subject and Body
        mailMsg.Subject = "subject";
        mailMsg.Body = "body";

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.virginmedia.com", 465);

        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials =
           new System.Net.NetworkCredential("x@y.com", "MyPassword");
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
        //smtpClient.
        smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
```

Cheers in advance
Robbo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your app.config.
Run the applicatin again. Now, you will see exactly where the timeout occurs in the log. If it's during connect, you're blocked by a firewall or using the wrong port. But maybe it's happing at another time?

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.Net">
      <listeners>
        <add name="TraceFile"/>
        <add name="TraceConsole"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
      <listeners>
        <add name="TraceFile"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="TraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="trace.log"/>
    <add name="TraceConsole" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener"/>
  </sharedListeners>
  <switches>
    <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
    <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
  </switches>
  <trace autoflush="true"/>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Cheers for the response.  Tried adding that and got the timeout.  Didn't get any more info out of it though.  Inner exception was null

Comment: There should be quite a lot of info in the log about what operation was being performed when the timeout occured.

Comment: Ah I'm an idiot, was looking in the wrong place for the log file. Got it now cheers